# Installation Homestead php Laravel Problems

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, app.yaml

I am trying to install Homestead Laravel php. I have install and initialised it but having trouble with the 'vagrant up' code in terminal.

This is the error message that I receive in the terminal when inside the homestead folder.

"There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: Users/simonayellowright/web/Sites"

---

ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: Users/name/web/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Sites/test/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

** NOTE ** that I changed the 'name' path from my name for security under folders/map

From other notices on here I understand that the .yaml file is often the problem but I cannot see where I would have an indent issue in my code - see above.

So in that case it must be my PATH. What should I know? What should I look for and do you know the cause of my error?

I am a bit new to php but very new to Laravel. I enjoyed that and think i need this to move onto the next stage. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Try changing `Users/name/web/Sites` to `/Users/name/web/Sites` with a leading slash.

Comment: Success!! Thank you Jeremy!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the path is incorrect, hence the error message:

> The host path of the shared folder is missing: Users/simonayellowright/web/Sites

You should have a leading slash:

```
/Users/simonayellowright/web/Sites
```